# Get a background jobs output through writing to a file

Tags: bash, files, io-redirection, raspbian

I am trying to get the output of a running background command I issued with

```
sudo wminput -r -w -c "$controls_config" > "$temp_output" &
exec 3< "$temp_output"

while true; do
    sleep 1
    read <&3 output
    if [[ "$output" = 'Ready' ]]; then
        echo "Controller $wiimote_counter Connected"
        break
    fi
done
```

but nothing is ever written to the file while the script is running. 
Only after I send a SIGINT it writes anything to the file(tried it with just the file as-well, but no luck).

is there another way to get the output of a background job the way i want to use it? i.e. continuously, until a certain output is reached.

Comment: Can `wminput` be told not to buffer its output?

Comment: not explicitly from going through its man page, thanks for pointing me in that direction!
is there a way to force a flush through bash?

Comment: now using 
`sudo stdbuf -oL wminput -r -w -c "$controls_config" > "$temp_output" &`
to flush newlines, will check when I'm back home - but it seems like it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @choroba's comment, I was directed towards the fact that the output is buffered. 

looking further I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin) stating that stdout is buffered by default. 

also, looking at the man pages for wminput gave no quick-solution,

so i went looking for a way to force a flush from the jobs stdout buffer to the file - and found the stdbuf command. [stdbuf docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html#stdbuf-invocation)

Which I use as-
`sudo stdbuf -oL wminput -r -w -c "$controls_config" > "$temp_output" &`

where -o stands for stdout

and -L for flushing the buffer on each newline

Thanks for the tip!